# nkf UTF-8 with Chinese characters?

Tags: command-line

So I have a file tmp.ahk that contains Chinese characters,

```
$ cat tmp.ahk
sendText("结婚吧")
```

and I wanted to convert the file to UTF-8 (with BOM) file. (The BOM is because in the later steps Autohotkey requires files to be BOM-ed)

```
$ file tmp.ahk 
tmp.ahk: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

So I used the nkf command to convert the file to a UTF-8 with BOM file, I did the following.

```
$ bash -c "nkf --overwrite --oc=UTF-8-BOM ./tmp.ahk"

$ file tmp.ahk
tmp.ahk: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text
```

But after that I found that the file content (the Chinese text part is modified to a garbled)

```
$ cat tmp.ahk
sendText("扈灘ゥ壼制")
```

What is causing this issue? How can I convert a file that contains Chinese texts to UTF8-BOM without getting a garbled? Thanks.

Comment: Probbably `nkf` is for Japanese. You can try with `sed`: `sed -i .bak '1s/^/\xef\xbb\xbf/' tmp.ahk`

Comment: It worked with your sed command. I should have done a `man` earlier. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

BOMs don't make much sense in UTF-8, as byte order is irrelevant there.

It looks like that Autohotkey is a Microsoft Windows application, which likely explains why it needs it.

Then you could just do:

```
unix2dos --add-bom your-file
```

Which would also convert the line delimiters from Unix-style (LF) to Microsoft style (CRLF).

Answer (score 0):

From [taliezin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/102632/taliezin)'s comment, with the GNU implementation of `sed`:

```bash
sed -i .bak '1s/^/\xef\xbb\xbf/' tmp.ahk
```

Adds the UTF-8 encoding of the BOM (U+FEFF) character at the start of the first line.